# Tabs with icons in Angular 9 - material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to use icons for the tab labels in angular 9 material. When I do this, I get an error when I try to use the  to set the icon I get the following error.

error NG8001: 'mat-tab-label' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-tab-label' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-tab-label' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: It'd be easier to help if you posted some code

Answer (score 0):

Did you import `import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material/tabs';` to app.modules.ts?